# How to determine if $3$ is a square $\mod 97$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

The answer is that it is since $10^2 \equiv 3 \mod 97$, but how do we determine that $3$ is in fact a square without having to find explicitly the square that is $3 \mod 97$ ($100$ in this case)?

Comment: Compute the Legendre symbol $(3/97)$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity

Comment: My professor says that if the symbol is $-1$, then the number is not a square $\mod p$, but if the symbol is $+1$, it does not necessarily imply that the number is a square.

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs, that is true about Jacobi symbols.  Legendre symbols are decisive for both +1 and -1, however they only work if the bottom number is prime.  Fortunately 97 is prime.